# section hides after puting it to the end of a nother section

Tags: html, css

i am already done with my Project , but there is one Problem that i could solved. i would like to have a Website with a Metro optic. the three div boxes on the left should be fixed so that only the middle part should be horizontal Scrolling. i would like to have now These three div boxes on the right sight too . but if i put them at the end of the `</section>` with the `id="Content"` are they gone. if i put theme just before the closing tag are they there but there are also moving horizontal and that's what i don't want.

```
 <section class="clearfix section" >    
     <h3 class="block-title">Klasse 7a</h3>
         <div class="row custom-row-three" >
           <div class="tile red "></div>     
           <div class="tile turquoise"></div>      
           <div class="tile orange"></div>
         </div> 
</section>
```

that is the html code from the three boxes which are now on the left side and i would like to have them on the right site too. but fixed.[School Project](http://hoojoo.awesom-media.de)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following styles -

```
.rightSection {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: perfect it works, but the scroll is not working at the beginning. i have to search the element and close than the control bar from google.

Comment: i updated the file now. if u visits the site for the first time, u will see no scrollbar, after open the element stuf and closing it it will show the scroll bar

Comment: I don't understand, I can see the scrollbar at the bottom of the page fine

Comment: from the beginning ? i use crome and my friend too . if we visit the side we can not scroll. we just cann scroll if we open the chrome developer tool and close it. only than is the scrollbar visible and the scroll effect there